# SqlException: The INSERT permission was denied on the object '', database '', schema 'dbo'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler

I have created a back end application which uses Entity framework to connect and write to the database.

Suddenly I am getting the following error:
SqlException: The INSERT permission was denied on the object '', database '', schema 'dbo'.

I checked my user which is db owner in the database. Add my user directly to the table itself.
I am still getting the error.
How can I view it in SQL Profiler which account executed the query?
This is a virtual machine and everything is installed using my account.

**Edit:1**

- The SQL Profiler is running inside the same machine where SQL server is install. It is a completely isolated environment. Everything runs inside the same machine.
- Everything is installed under one account and that is mine account. No other account is used.
- SQL Server Agent (MSSQLServer) is running under NT Service\SQLServeragent
- SQL Server : NT Service\MSSQLSERVER
- My account has sysadmin and db_owner rights on the database
- gave direct access to the tables as well, but still no luck

Comment: Since you said you are using SQL Profiler just look at the column named "LoginName". It will show you the sql user. And yes it will capture the event even though permission to insert is not allowed.

Comment: the query executed by the application does not show up in the sql profiler. I don't see the database there.

Comment: Then either your application is connecting to a different server or your filtering in profiler is preventing it from displaying. Check your db context to make sure you know what server it is connecting to. You could also run exec sp_who and/or exec sp_who2 to view active connections.

Comment: it is connecting to the right sql server and there is no filtering applied.

Comment: Then you have something funky going on for sure. The connection has to show up in profiler assuming you are looking at the right server in profiler. You say they are db_owner in the database. Does that mean they have the role of db_owner, or that user is the db_owner. Yes it does make a difference because you can deny things to the db_owner role.

Comment: Are you executing SQL Profiler inside the virtual machine as well? Given VM guests have an entirely different network configuration than the host the EF app could be connecting somewhere entirely different than you're expecting.

Comment: Please see my last comment in my post. everything runs from the same machine.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of capturing the offending batch/query in SQL Profiler, I'd suspect that perhaps you aren't capturing the correct events? If an exception is being thrown, the only way you'd be able to see which actual SQL batch/statement caused the exception would be by including "starting" events (in addition to the more common captured "completed" events).

Running a trace with the following should allow you to see which procedure/statement is throwing the exception if you are capturing the correct events, those you'd want to capture would/could include:

1. SQL:BatchStarting
2. SQL:BatchCompleted
3. SQL:StmtStarting
4. SQL:StmtCompleted
5. RPC:Starting
6. RPC:Completed
7. SP:Starting
8. SP:Completed
9. SP:StmtStarting
10. SP:StmtCompleted
11. Exception

You mentioned you're using EF, so you could likely safely ignore events 5 & 6, and also 7-9 if you're not actually executing a sproc. Be sure you capture all associated columns in the trace as well (should be the default if you are running a trace using the Profiler tool). The Exception class will include the actual error in your trace, which should allow you to see the immediate preceding statement within the same SPID that threw the exception. You must include the starting events in addition to the completed events as an exception that occurs will preclude the associated completed events from firing in the trace.